# How to use different file sever instead of default file system folder in drupal 7?

Tags: file, drupal-7, replication, cdn, fileserver

How to use different file sever instead of default file system folder in drupal 7 ?

We are trying to replace the drupal public:// folder for storing files into one remote file server so that only one file server will be there for all the server instances. How can we implement the solution as well we need.

I am already using file replication of windows to replicate the files folder for the instances but we don't want to use file replication feature here, we want to replace file replication feature.

Can anyone help me out with this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Amazon S3 or any other S3 compatible system is ok for you you can try these modules:

https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs

https://www.drupal.org/project/media_mover

Also this tutorial may be useful to you:
http://www.symphonythemes.com/drupal-blog/easy-amazon-s3-drupal-s3fs